# Android/Gradle: Where is this dependency embedded?

Tags: android, build, dependencies, gradle

I'm using the new Android build system that is based on Gradle, together with the early access preview Android Studio. Now, I have two projects: an Android library project, and an Android app project (basically a demo for the library).

In the library project I have added a dependency to the gson library, so my `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
}
```

Still, everything works fine and dandy and I'm able to use gson in my library and then my app. But I want to understand **where** this library is embedded. I've opened both the `.aar` that is built by the library project and the `.apk` of the demo app. I was expecting to find the jars for the two dependencies in at least one of these, but I didn't.

So where are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Android Tools](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects) website:

> These items, plus the output of the compilation of the project’s own source code, are sent to dex for bytecode conversion and inclusion in the final APK.

In other words, they are in your *.dex file inside the APK.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But AFAIK the app project only knows about the `.aar` file of the library project. This means that the `.aar` project needs to specify the dependency somewhere. And I can't find that.

Answer (score 1):

As @SharkyXTS said, the code from any external dependencies is compiled into the final .dex file inside your APK. The reason why you can't find any references to these dependencies in the .aar is because there aren't any.

The .aar format is only supported through Maven for now, so dependencies are found through there. I believe there are plans to eventually support local .aar dependencies (without Maven), but the Android plugin isn't quite there yet. You can see [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55863) for more information.

Comment: Actually, it's referenced locally, because in my demo app `gradle.build` I have the dependency defined as `compile project (':my-library')`, so I guess it's pulling the dependency from the library project's `gradle.build` file.

Comment: You're right. In that case, Gradle isn't even using the .aar, it's building the library separately and then copying it over to your app project.